# How to compare values from the joined table with cross join ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run this query :

```
SELECT business.name as businessName i.ratingCount , i.ratingSum
FROM business
cross join
  (
    SELECT SUM(rating.rating) as ratingSum,COUNT(rating.bussId) as ratingCount 
    FROM rating 
    WHERE rating.bussId = business.bussId   
  )i
```

but I got this error `Unknown column 'business.bussId'` ! How to fix it ?

```
I don't want to use left join !
```

Comment: You probably want to spell "business" wrong consistently. Or, you know, spelling it right everywhere is also an option. But it's the consistency that's important.

Comment: @MattGibson I correct it ! but that's not the problem , do you know How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use it as correlated sub query

```
SELECT business.name as businessName,
       ( select sum(rating.bussId)
         from rating 
         where rating.bussId = business.bussId
       ) as ratingSum,
       ( select count(rating.bussId)
         from rating 
         where rating.bussId = business.bussId
       ) as ratingCount
FROM business
```

or you can use left join and do group by

```
SELECT business.name as businessName,
       sum(rating.bussId) as ratingSum,
       count(rating.bussId) as ratingCount
 FROM business
 left join rating
 on business.bussId = rating.bussId
 group by business.name
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but why i couldn't do that with cross join ?

Comment: @David, you can access the table in side a correlated subquery in the same select not valid in the cross join.